# How can I find the min and max of a specific position in a loop of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
        list1.append(random.randrange(1,101))
    list2.append(list1)
    list1=[]

for i in list2:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=",")

    print(" (Sum: ", sum(i), " Average: ", (sum(i)/len(i)), ")", sep="") 
    print()
```

I want to be able to find the largest and smallest number on each column. So for example, the output would be:

```
1,91,46, (Sum: 138 Average: 46.0)

82,62,21, (Sum: 165 Average: 55.0)

39,52,41, (Sum: 132 Average: 44.0)

60,69,45, (Sum: 174 Average: 58.0)

20,21,7, (Sum: 48 Average: 16.0)

Largest number of first column: 82      Smallest number of first column: 1
Largest number of second column: 91     Smallest number of second column: 21 
Largest number of third column: 46      Smallest number of third column: 7
```

I know of min/max, is there some way I can use those to get these results? Or do I have to use a different method? Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you can organize your lists into 2D arrays, you could use numpy array operations (sum, mean...)

Comment: Did you try considering using a `list of lists`? Do you plan to have a `5x3` matrix from the sample you've shown above?

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose (swap rows/columns) a nested list by using `zip(*rows)`

```
rows = [[randrange(1, 101) for col in range(5)] for row in range(3)]

for column in zip(*rows):
    print(
        column, 
        'sum:', sum(column), 
        'avg:', int(sum(column) / len(column)),
        'min:', min(column),
        'max:', max(column),
    )
```

Sample output:

```
(5, 22, 95) sum: 122 avg: 40 min: 5 max: 95
(92, 88, 67) sum: 247 avg: 82 min: 67 max: 92
(97, 61, 3) sum: 161 avg: 53 min: 3 max: 97
(95, 37, 67) sum: 199 avg: 66 min: 37 max: 95
(47, 13, 29) sum: 89 avg: 29 min: 13 max: 47
```

If you are using numpy, you can use [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) instead of a nested list. Use `array.T` (transpose) to iterate over columns instead of rows.

```
for column in numpy.array(rows).T:
    print(column, column.sum(), column.mean(dtype=int), column.min(), column.max())


[ 5 22 95] 122 40 5 95
[92 88 67] 247 82 67 92
[97 61  3] 161 53 3 97
[95 37 67] 199 66 37 95
[47 13 29] 89 29 13 47
```

Comment: For good order, there is no concept of "2-dimensional list" [this is `numpy` or array terminology]. What you have is a list of lists (which are not *required* to be the same length as in an `int` array). But `zip` is the way to go. +1

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do it is as follow :

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
for i in list2:
    col1.append(i[0])
    col2.append(i[1])
    col3.append(i[2])
print("Largest number of first column:", max(col1), ",Smallest number of first column:", min(col1) )
print("Largest number of second column:", max(col2), ",Smallest number of second column:", min(col2) )
print("Largest number of third column:", max(col3), ",Smallest number of third column:", min(col3) )
```